# How can I automate the reading of object properties from external sources (such as a file) in Java?

Tags: java, properties, annotations

I was wondering if there's some way which allows me to automate the updating of object properties from some source as a file or a map.

To elaborate, suppose I have an object with properties `x, y, width, height` of type `Float`. And I have a map with key-value pair for the properties in the form `<String, Float>`. To update the properties of the object, I would iterate over the map and do something like:

```
if (key.equals("x")) x = (Float) map.get(key);
else if(key.equals("y")) y = (Float) map.get(key);
else if(key.equals("width")) width = (Float) map.get(key);
else if(key.equals("height")) height = (Float) map.get(key);
```

If I add more properties to the class, I'll have to keep adding code like this. So my question basically is, is there a way to automate this process so that it'll be easy to add new properties and update them as above? Possibly by the use of annotations?

Thanks,
stormweaver

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html might help you with properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that using reflection ([check out this link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)). If every class attribute is mapped to a property, then you could get all class attributes and iterate over them properly to update the property values. That way you don't need to keep adding if clauses.

Does it help?

Comment: Yes, I checked reflection and I guess it pretty much does my job. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, seems there are no third party tools available for doing this directly, I'll have to write some reflection code.

Answer (score 1):

[`BeanUtils.populate(this, map)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29) from [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/):

> Populate the JavaBeans properties of the specified bean, based on the specified name/value pairs.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. That seems like what I'm looking for. But I guess the map passed to the populate method is of <String, String> type. But I need to work with a map of the type <String, Object>, since the values in the map shall be extracted from serialized objects. Will BeanUtils still help me in this case? Anyway, maybe I can write another function based on the populate() function...

Comment: hm, yes, it seems that PropertyUtils does not have a direct equivalent to that